# How do I call command-line tools from a standalone java library using WL?

Tags: windows, java, command-line, run

I have the following command which when I run on the windows command line, works perfectly fine.

```
"C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Wolfram Desktop\13.0\SystemFiles\Java\Windows-x86-64\bin\java.exe" -jar "...path...\pdfbox-app-2.0.25.jar" PDFSplit -startPage 5 -endPage 10 -outputPrefix "XXX-X-XXXX[1.1,1.2,1.3]" "...path...\test.pdf"
```

This uses `java` which comes bundled with Wolfram and executes a standalone library's (`"pdfbox-app-2.0.25.jar"`) command-line tool `PDFSplit` with options `-startPage`, `-endPage` `outputPrefix` and passes the file `"...path...\test.pdf"` as input.

All I am looking for is a `Run`,`RunProcess` or `StartProcess` command that will help me execute this command from Wolfram notebook.

Probably there is a better way to execute this by using the `` JLink` ``  library. If you know how to do that then that would help even more.

Comment: I don't how to make it work. I tried `process=StartProcess[$SystemShell];` then `WriteLine[process,"... command mentioned above ..."];` but nothing happens. Sending the `command` directly via `Terminal` works but sending it through `WriteLine` is not working.

Comment: `RunProcess` is more appropriate here than `StartProcess` I think.  Something like `RunProcess[{"path\to\java.exe", "-jar", "\"...path...\pdfbox-app-2.0.25.jar\"", "PDFSplit", "-startPage", "5", <the rest of the arguments, split into strings>]`